# Calculate Spearman correlation Rho using cor between paired samples between two matrices

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics, correlation, qiime

I'm having some problems with trying to run cor.test, based on two OTU tables (essentially an abundance matrix).

I have a table with 8 different sampling spots (columns 1 to 44) and for each sampling spot I measured a variable (VARIABLE1, first row) and the presence of a series of species (OTUs on the rows). Here you can see an example of what these OTU tables look like below:

Samples 1 - 8 are the columns

```
#OTUID  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
OTU1    0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0
OTU2    0   0   0   0   0   0   13  0
OTU3    5   99  0   0   0   0   0   0
OTU4    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
OTU5    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
OTU6    0   0   19  0   9   236 59  2
OTU7    0   55  0   2   4   2   3   0
OTU8    0   44  10  5   0   0   7   0
OTU9    6   0   13  2   0   0   17  6
OTU10   0   100 0   0   0   3   0   0
OTU11   4   13  0   0   2   1   2   0
OTU12   0   0   0   0   0   101 1   0
```

I have two of these tables in .biom format. I want to calculate spearman's correlation coefficients (R) between paired samples (e.g  sample1(OTU table 1) vs sample1(OTU table 2); sample2(OTU table 1) vs sample2(OTU table 2), etc....etc) for EACH OTU. I have approximately 100 samples and abundance data for 4000 OTUs. Hence, I want to calculate the correlation coefficient for 44 pairs of data for each of the 4000 OTUs. So basically just correlating an ~4k long vector once per sample.

Finally I will take the average of the correlations for the 4k long vector for each sample and plot these averages on a scatterplot.

Keep in mind all my abundance data is in this .biom format! I've converted it all to .txt to make it easier to manipulate.

Thanks again!!

An example of how this would look as [below](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4584126/figure/Fig2/):

[image]

Here is some sample data:

OTU table 1:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah_Q0DzXKdX-gZUl8SCetQdYE8S3CA

OTU table 2:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah_Q0DzXKdX-gZUnaIwEIJiYMnrQIA

Comment: So is there a problem or an error that you are getting or you want the code to create it?

Comment: I am looking for a code to create it. Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you defining the correlation between these two matrices? How many correlation values are you looking to create? It's not clear to me what you think the desired output is.

Comment: I think they are doing row-by-row spearman across the two tables (of equal rows), so their desired output is a spearman coefficient for each OTU row

Comment: I am attempting to do something similar to the paper here: http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v31/n9/full/nbt.2676.html. Rbierman is spot on. That is exactly what I want to do. Then I would visualize the correlation between paired rows with one OTU table on the X axis and the other on the Y axis.

Comment: Provide 2 matrices for testing. [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @zx8754 I added the matrices for testing and clarified what I was trying to do.

Comment: I solved the problem.